# How to remap ctrl-x with key-chord

Tags: key-bindings

How to remap `C-x` with key-chord mode.

(key-chord-define-global "uu" 'what-goes-here?)

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord

Comment: The question is not clear, to me. What do you want the effect to be? Something about changing the behavior of `C-x`? Something about `uu`?

Comment: Right now I have bound chords to various function i.e. bb when pressed very quickly, changes the buffer. I would like to be able to hit uu very fast and be in the mini-buffer behind ctrl-x. So I could type uu - b and and it would be the same as ctrl-x b

Comment: What's `C-x` bound to, for you. Normally it's a prefix key. Are you thinking of `M-x`, perhaps?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do, first for C-x and then also for M-x. Instead of using a prefix key I want to type 'uu' quickly and have it behave *as if* I had typed the prefix key. When I type 'uu' slowly it should insert 'uu'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `(key-chord-define-global "uu" ctl-x-map)`, since `ctl-x-map` is
what `C-x` is usually bound to.

Comment: ctl-x-map seems to be a variable, whereas I am looking for a function

Comment: @tjb ctrl-x-map is, as you say, a variable. Its value is a keymap holding all the bindings under `C-x`. I don't know about this `key-chord-define-global` command, but for the standard `global-set-key`, you can binds a key to keymap and it becomes a prefix for those bindings. So `(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") ctl-x-map)` would make `C-z` an alias of `C-x`.

Comment: By the way, @tjb, I just installed `key-chord` and tried my suggestion and it works!

Comment: I get the following error when I try the answer: `Wrong type argument: commandp, ctl-x-map`.

Comment: @tjb Weird! I just tried it again and it works for me. I installed the `key-chord` package from MELPA to try this (it's version key-chord-20160227.1238). Is that what you're using?

Comment: @tjb Wait a second, did you put a quote in front of `ctl-x-map` instead of following my suggestion (i.e., did you use `(key-chord-define-global "uu" 'ctl-x-map)`)? If so, just remove the quote and you're probably good to go!

Comment: Omar, thank you! You are right, I did not read carefully enough!

Comment: do you know if there is a similar way to do this for the meta key?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do this for meta, @tjb. You might want to ask that as a separte question.